# Aerospike java client failure on scanAll

Tags: java, aerospike

I using the following method in order to `truncate` data from aerospike `namespace.set.bins`:

```
    // Setting LUT
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(startTime + 1262304000000L) // uses CITRUSLEAF_EPOCH  - see https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-to-use-view-and-calulate-last-update-time-lut-for-the-truncate-command/4330

    logger.info(s"truncate($startTime = ${calendar.getTime}, durableDelete = $durableDelete) on ${config.toRecoverMap}")

    // Define Scan and Write Policies
    val writePolicy = new WritePolicy()
    val scanPolicy = new ScanPolicy()
    writePolicy.durableDelete = durableDelete
    scanPolicy.filterExp = Exp.build(Exp.le(Exp.lastUpdate(), Exp.`val`(calendar)))

    // Scan all records such as LUT <= startTime
    config.toRecoverMap.flatMap { case (namespace, mapOfSetsToBins) =>
      for ((set, bins) <- mapOfSetsToBins) yield {
        val recordCount = new AtomicInteger(0)
        client.scanAll(scanPolicy, namespace, set, new ScanCallback() {
          override def scanCallback(key: Key, record: Record): Unit = {
            val requiresNullify = bins.filter(record.bins.containsKey(_)).distinct // Instead of making bulk requests which maybe not be needed and load AS
            if (requiresNullify.nonEmpty) {
              client.put(writePolicy, key, requiresNullify.map(Bin.asNull): _*)
              logger.debug(s"${recordCount.incrementAndGet()}: (${requiresNullify.mkString(",")}) Bins of Record: $record with $key are set to NULL")
            }
          }
        })

        logger.info(s"Totally $recordCount records affected during the truncate operation on $namespace.$set.$bins")
        recordCount.get
      }
    }
  }
```

This is failed on:

```
...
2021-08-08 16:51:30,551 [Aerospike-6] DEBUG c.d.a.c.r.services.AerospikeService.scanCallback(55) - 33950: (IsActive) Bins of Record: (gen:3),(exp:0),(bins:(IsActive:0)) with test-recovery-set-multi-1:null:95001b26e70dbb35e1487802ebbc857eceb92246 are set to NULL
```

for reason:

```
Error -11,6,0,30000,0,5: Max retries exceeded: 5
com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: Error -11,6,0,30000,0,5: Max retries exceeded: 5
    at com.aerospike.client.query.PartitionTracker.isComplete(PartitionTracker.java:282)
    at com.aerospike.client.command.ScanExecutor.scanPartitions(ScanExecutor.java:70)
    at com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.scanAll(AerospikeClient.java:1519)
    at com.aerospike.connect.reloader.services.AerospikeService.$anonfun$truncate$3(AerospikeService.scala:50)
    at com.aerospike.connect.reloader.services.AerospikeService.$anonfun$truncate$3$adapted(AerospikeService.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:575)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.prependedAll(List.scala:153)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$.from(List.scala:651)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$.from(List.scala:648)
    at scala.collection.IterableFactory$Delegate.from(Factory.scala:288)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Iterable$.from(Iterable.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Iterable$.from(Iterable.scala:32)
    at scala.collection.IterableOps$WithFilter.map(Iterable.scala:884)
    at com.aerospike.connect.reloader.services.AerospikeService.$anonfun$truncate$1(AerospikeService.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.flatMap(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:117)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.flatMap$(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.flatMap(Map.scala:241)
    at com.aerospike.connect.reloader.services.AerospikeService.truncate(AerospikeService.scala:47)
    at com.aerospike.connect.reloader.tests.services.AerospikeServiceSpec.$anonfun$new$2(AerospikeServiceSpec.scala:23)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike$$anon$3.apply(AnyWordSpecLike.scala:1077)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture$(TestSuite.scala:195)
    at com.aerospike.connect.reloader.tests.services.AerospikeServiceSpec.withFixture(AerospikeServiceSpec.scala:13)
    at org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike.invokeWithFixture$1(AnyWordSpecLike.scala:1075)
    at org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike.$anonfun$runTest$1(AnyWordSpecLike.scala:1087)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:306)
    at org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike.runTest(AnyWordSpecLike.scala:1087)
    at org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike.runTest$(AnyWordSpecLike.scala:1069)
    at com.aerospike.connect.reloader.tests.services.AerospikeServiceSpec.runTest(AerospikeServiceSpec.scala:13)
    at org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike.$anonfun$runTests$1(AnyWordSpecLike.scala:1146)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.$anonfun$runTestsInBranch$1(Engine.scala:413)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:390)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.$anonfun$runTestsInBranch$1(Engine.scala:427)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:396)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:475)
    at org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike.runTests(AnyWordSpecLike.scala:1146)
    at org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike.runTests$(AnyWordSpecLike.scala:1145)
    at com.aerospike.connect.reloader.tests.services.AerospikeServiceSpec.runTests(AerospikeServiceSpec.scala:13)
    at org.scalatest.Suite.run(Suite.scala:1112)
    at org.scalatest.Suite.run$(Suite.scala:1094)
    at com.aerospike.connect.reloader.tests.services.AerospikeServiceSpec.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterAll$$super$run(AerospikeServiceSpec.scala:13)
    at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:213)
    at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)
    at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run$(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:208)
    at com.aerospike.connect.reloader.tests.services.AerospikeServiceSpec.org$scalatest$wordspec$AnyWordSpecLike$$super$run(AerospikeServiceSpec.scala:13)
    at org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike.$anonfun$run$1(AnyWordSpecLike.scala:1191)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:535)
    at org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike.run(AnyWordSpecLike.scala:1191)
    at org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike.run$(AnyWordSpecLike.scala:1189)
    at com.aerospike.connect.reloader.tests.services.AerospikeServiceSpec.run(AerospikeServiceSpec.scala:13)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:45)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13(Runner.scala:1320)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13$adapted(Runner.scala:1314)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1314)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:993)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:971)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1480)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:971)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:798)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2or3(ScalaTestRunner.java:38)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:25)
```

Any ideas why its happening?

---

LUT method:

```
def calculateCurrentLUT(): Long = {
    logger.info("calculateCurrentLUTs() Triggered")
    val policy = new WritePolicy()
    policy.setTimeout(config.operationTimeoutInMillis)
    val key = new Key(config.toRecover.head.namespace, AerospikeConfiguration.dummySetName, AerospikeConfiguration.dummyKey)
    client.put(policy, key, new Bin(AerospikeConfiguration.dummyBin, "Used by the Recovery process to calculate current machine startTime"))
    client.execute(policy, key, AerospikeConfiguration.packageName, "getLUT").asInstanceOf[Long]
  }
```

with:

```
def registerUDFs(): RegisterTask = {
    logger.info(s"registerUDFs() Triggered")
    val policy = new WritePolicy()
    policy.setTimeout(config.operationTimeoutInMillis)
    client.registerUdfString(policy,  """
        |function getLUT(r)
        |    return record.last_update_time(r)
        |end
        |""", AerospikeConfiguration.packageName + ".lua", Language.LUA)
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AerospikeException: Error -11,6,0,30000,0,5: Max retries exceeded: 5`  means -11: error code, maximum retry attempts on this operation exceeded specified value. Shows 6 iterations (orig+maxretries) and you specified max retries at 5. Your connection settings are: 0 - for connectTimeout - wait to create initial socket, 0 is default, 30000 or 30s is your time to close an idle socket, 0 is the total timeout for this scan is operation - 0 means don't timeout which is correct for scans, 5 is the times you retried - looks like server is not responding back to client scan call in 30seconds and client closes the idle socket and retries and after 5 re-tries throws an Exception. Something is obviously wrong - check server log for more clues. For e.g. Are you using the correct server version that supports Expressions for scans?  Second, I would check your computation of LUT comparison expression. if the filter expression is evaluating to false, scan will just return an EOF on completion, no matching records -but if socket times out before that, scan will go into a retry.

Comment: Thank you very much @pgupta! - regarding the LUT transposed scale, i think i missed the point, without the citrusleaf epoach i get zero results, do you recommend to do it other way? i added the LUT calculation on the post

Comment: In Java, API documentation says - Exp.lastUpdate() returns last update timestamp in nanoseconds since 1/1/1970. I edited what I said earlier about what is on the server... the Java client is presenting it to you from 1/1/70.

Comment: So, for your comparison condition, the time stamp you are supplying should accordingly be in the correct time scale. For example, time start of today was: $ date --date="2021-08-09 00:00:00" +%s%N
1628467200000000000. Since you are comparing, make sure resolution is same - nanoseconds.  Do some debug printfs and make sure your Exp condition is good. I am not exactly following why you are adding citrusleaf_epoch value, and in milliseconds. CL-epoch: $ date --date="2010-01-01 00:00:00" +%s%N
1262304000000000000

Comment: Sorry for basic question but i really want to make sure its works, how can i query the LUT from the aql / client, without the epoch i cannot find any results which is strange, the following returns zero: `val now = aerospikeService.calculateCurrentLUT()
      aerospikeService.truncate(startTime = now, true) shouldBe true // Its not a test yet, but its delete all records` but its should delete all

Comment: You cannot bring LUT to the client - no api to read it into the client. You can use it in expressions - they will pull from server metadata and use at the server level. The value you are supplying for comparison - that should be in nanoseconds from 1/1/70

Comment: Thanks @pgupta, and the `calculateCurrentLUT` which is called (first registerUDFs is called) is returning Long as nanoseconds from 1/1/70? if so - its not making any sense to me that `val now = aerospikeService.calculateCurrentLUT()       aerospikeService.truncate(startTime = now, true)` return zero records :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235804/discussion-between-pgupta-and-zvi-mints).